# Only one match is returned after using (.|\s)*

Tags: python, regex

String:

```
Person1(has(1, 1) has(2, 2)
    has(3, 3) 
    had(4, 4) had(5, 5))
Person2(has(6, 6) had(7, 7))
```

I'd like to select all contents in `has()` for `Person1`, i.e `['1, 1', '2, 2', '3, 3']`.

I tried: `has\((\d, \d)\)(.|\s)*Person2` with Global pattern flags, but only `1, 1` was returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution using `re.findall()` function:

```
import re

s = '''
Person1(has(1, 1) has(2, 2)
    has(3, 3)
    had(4, 4) had(5, 5))
Person2(has(6, 6) had(7, 7))'''

has_items = re.findall(r'(?<!Person2\()has\(([^()]+)\)', s)
print(has_items)
```

The output:

```
['1, 1', '2, 2', '3, 3']
```

---

- `(?<!Person2\()` - lookbehind negative assertion, ensures that crucial `has` substring is not preceded with `Person2(`
- `([^()]+)` - the 1st captured group containing `has` items

---

To grep `has` items for a certain `Person` use the following ***unified*** approach with extended example:

```
def grepPersonItems(s, person):
    person_items = []
    person_group = re.search(r'(' + person + '\(.*?\)\))', s, re.DOTALL)

    if person_group:
        person_items = re.findall(r'has\(([^()]+)\)', person_group.group())
    return person_items

s = '''
Person1(has(1, 1) has(2, 2)
    has(3, 3)
    had(4, 4) had(5, 5))
Person2(has(6, 6) had(7, 7), has(8,8)) Person3(has(2, 6) had(7, 7), has(9, 9))'''

print('Person1: ', person1_items)
print('Person2: ', person2_items)
print('Person3: ', person3_items)

print(person1_items)
print(person2_items)
print(person3_items)
```

The output:

```
Person1:  ['1, 1', '2, 2', '3, 3']
Person2:  ['6, 6', '8, 8']
Person3:  ['2, 6', '9, 9']
```

Comment: Can I only select `has` for `Person1` or `Person2`? If `Person2` has more than 1 `has`, those after the 1st one will be selected, too. Thanks.

Comment: @Harrison, elaborate your question, do you want to grep all `has` items for both `Person1` and `Person2` or for any possible Persons?

Comment: My original question was to get all `has` for `Person1`, but if you could also provide another regex for `Person2`, it would be great. I simplified `Person2` in the question, it also can have multiple `has` and multiple lines.

Comment: If you added another `has` for `Person2`, `(?<!Person2\()has\(([^()]+)\)` will select that too.

Comment: @Harrison, enjoy my unified approach with extended example

Answer (score 1):

Why not parse it fully and then you can pick up whatever you may need - you'll need two patterns, one to grab each person and it's contents, and the other to grab individual parts within them + you can add some more parsing to get individual elements and convert them to native Python types. Something like:

```
import collections
import re

persons = re.compile(r"(Person\d+)\(((?:.*?\(.*?\)\s*)+)\)")
contents = re.compile(r"(\w+)\((.*?)\)")

def parse_input(data, parse_inner=True, map_inner=str):
    result = {}  # store for our parsed data
    for match in persons.finditer(data):  # loop through our `Persons`
        person = match.group(1)  # grab the first group to get our Person
        elements = collections.defaultdict(list)  # store for the parsed inner elements
        for element in contents.finditer(match.group(2)):  # loop through the has/had/etc.
            element_name = element.group(1)  # the first group holds the name
            element_data = element.group(2)  # this is the inner content of each has/had/etc.
            if parse_inner:  # if we want to parse the inner elements...
                element_data = [map_inner(x.strip()) for x in element_data.split(",")]
            elements[element_name].append(element_data)  # add our inner results
        result[person] = elements  # add persons to our result
    return result  # well, obvious...
```

Then you can parse everything and access it to your heart's content. The most basic example would be:

```
test = """Person1(has(1, 1) has(2, 2)
    has(3, 3)
    had(4, 4) had(5, 5))
Person2(has(6, 6) had(7, 7))"""

parsed = parse_input(test, False)  # basic string grab

print(parsed["Person1"]["has"])  # ['1, 1', '2, 2', '3, 3']
print(parsed["Person2"]["has"])  # ['6, 6']
print(parsed["Person2"]["had"])  # ['7, 7']
```

But then you can do so much more... You can have multiple added persons and have it 'converted' to an actual Python structure:

```
test = """Person1(has(1, 1) has(2, 2)
    has(3, 3)
    had(4, 4) had(5, 5))
Person2(has(6, 6) had(7, 7))
Person3(has(1, 2) has(3, 4) has(4, 5) foo(6, 7))"""

parsed = parse_input(test, True, int)  # parses everything and auto-converts to int

print(parsed["Person3"]["has"])  # [[1, 2], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
print(parsed["Person3"]["has"][1])  # [3, 4]
print(sum(parsed["Person3"]["foo"][0]))  # 13
print(parsed["Person1"]["has"][1] + parsed["Person2"]["has"][0])  # [2, 2, 6, 6]
# etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try this approach which i guess is dynamic and simple for all person. It splits and parse the string and push each desired array in a dictionary of Person.

Sample Source ([run here](http://ideone.com/3621jW)):

```
import re

regex = r"has\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)"

dict={}
test_str = ("Person1(has(1, 1) has(2, 2)\n"
    "    has(3, 3) \n"
    "    had(4, 4) had(5, 5))\n"
    "Person2(had(6, 6) has(7, 7))\n"
    "Person3(had(6, 6) has(8, 8))")

res=re.split(r"(Person\d+)",test_str)
currentKey="";
for rs in res:
    if "Person" in rs:
        currentKey=rs;
    elif currentKey !="":
        matches = re.finditer(regex, rs, re.DOTALL)
        ar=[]
        for match in matches:
            ar.append(match.group(1)+","+match.group(2))
        dict[currentKey]=ar;
print(dict)
```

output would be:

```
{'Person1': ['1,1', '2,2', '3,3'], 'Person2': ['7,7'], 'Person3': ['8,8']}
```